# Would ya take some time to guess what I am?

Tags: riddle

The bridge I helped build is not meant for holding

I wield symbolic tattoos

When cut I show no bleeding

And when seen I don't show my shoes

I've also been spliced.

What am I?

Hint:

> I can be very tricky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going with

> a face card,

and I'll go out on a limb and say it's

> the King of Hearts.

Leaning heavily on the answers already given by @Matt Nau and @gtwebb, here's my variation:

When I'm a bridge, I'm not meant for holding

> As a high value card in bridge, you usually don't want to hold a King, and as a heart, it is a major suit.

I wield symbolic tattoos

> The suit and value markings describe the card

When cut I show no bleeding

> [Look at him](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/06/King_of_hearts2.svg/165px-King_of_hearts2.svg.png) - he's stabbing himself in the head without bleeding.  Also, when you cut the deck, no gore is encountered.

And when seen I don't show my shoes

> You can't see his feet (see the splice).  Alternatively, the dealer's shoe is generally full of unseen cards.  Seen cards would not be in the shoe.

I've also been spliced.

> He has two heads.  His body was spliced in the middle with a clone.

Comment: Perfect! That was my exact reasoning.

Comment: +1 to you for making me do a crash course on the rules of bridge.

Comment: Good job. :/ (You cost me an accept... :P) +1 anyways.

Answer (score 7):

> Cards/Bridge game?

When I'm a bridge, I'm not meant for holding

> Bridge the card game

I wield symbolic tattoos

> The suits

When cut I show no bleeding

> Cut the deck = split

And when seen I don't show my shoes

> A deck is sometimes called a shoe

I've also been spliced.

> Also not sure; maybe another refernce to splitting the deck?

The hint:

> A trick is something in the game - [see this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trick-taking_game)/Card tricks *(Thanks, @Angelo!)*

Comment: You're close, but you've missed the double meaning (;

Comment: the hint could be related to magic/magicians.

Answer (score 5):

I am

> Ethernet Cabling?

When I'm a bridge, I'm not meant for holding

> Ethernet can be used to bridge routers

I wield symbolic tattoos

> Markings show cable specs

When cut I show no bleeding

> Cables are cut all the time. They just have wires

And when seen I don't show my shoes

> Shoes are an item used to make cables

I've also been spliced.

> Cables are spliced for different purposes

Comment: nice reasoning, though the hint doesn't quite suit it.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps

> A deck of cards

When I'm a bridge, I'm not meant for holding

> Bridging as in part of shuffling

I wield symbolic tattoos

> Marked with 4 suits

When cut I show no bleeding

> Cut the deck

And when seen I don't show my shoes

> Not sure perhaps something to do with a dealing shoe

I've also been spliced.

> games like magic the gathering can splice a card onto another one.

Comment: You were ninja'd.

Comment: You are close, but haven't quite solved it!

Comment: @Jason_ Does that mean that my answer (Which is above) is also incorrect, as they are basically the same thing, with the exception of mine also being Bridge?

Comment: @Mithrandir Yes, I'm waiting for the best reasoning scince you both answered about the same time.

Comment: @Jason_ See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

> Genes or DNA

When I'm a bridge, I'm not meant for holding

> Engineered DNA

I wield symbolic tattoos

> DNA has adenine(A), cytosine(C), guanine(G) and thymine(T). The symbols are used to represent the sugar.

When cut I show no bleeding

> Genes and DNA can be cut and pasted but don't bleed

And when seen I don't show my shoes

> Not sure on this one

I've also been spliced.

> Gene Splicing

Comment: Very interesting take on it.